# find file without extension in php

Tags: php

I try to file particular file name from particular directory.

**For example :** 
my user upload profile pic that already rename (with there username) it via php with same extension (jpg, png or gif)

Now I have want to find that file with start from $username and use it but I don't know filetype. need via php.

can anyone suggest me how to do it ? 
I try pathinfo() and .basename but unsuccessful.

Comment: go with [glob](http://php.net/glob)

Comment: thanks a ton, got it here is my command, foreach (glob($myfile) as $filename) {
    echo "$filename size " . filesize($filename) . "\n";
 echo $filename . "\n";  // filename received via search

}

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [glob](http://php.net/glob) to find a specific pathname using some patterns :

> glob — Find pathnames matching a pattern

which returns :

> Returns an array containing the matched files/directories, an empty
>   array if no file matched or FALSE on error.

a quick example :

```
$path = "/path/to/your/files/";

$files = glob($path . $username . ".*", GLOB_ERR);

// do thing with your $files array
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `scandir()`.

```
$dir = "/path/to/directory";
$scans = scandir($dir);
$files = array();
$username = "username";
foreach($scans as $k=>$v){
  if (preg_match('/'.$username.'.$/', $v))
    array_push($files ,['id'=>$k,'filename'=>$v]);
}
```

at the end `$files` will contain the array. `$dir` need to be `absolute` or `relative` path to your directory.

Answer (score 0):

The provided answers are potential solutions to your problem.

However it's very important that you know the source of the provided username.

Is it coming from a database or client?

Can the username contain special characters?

To show you what I mean, let's have a look at the provided answers:

```
$files = glob($path . $username . ".*", GLOB_ERR);
```

If `$username` can contain special characters like `/` or `.` you will be running into nasty security issues.

**It's important than you know the source AND which usernames are valid.**

The same can be said about the regex solution:

```
preg_match('/'.$username.'.$/', $v)
```

You only need a special character (like `$`) in the username to break the regex.

*I'm not saying these solutions are wrong or bad, just that you need to be very careful.*

Since you did not specify what $username can be, here a pretty versatile solution (and how I personally would do it) that should work in most cases:

```
<?php

$username = '..';
$dir      = opendir('/path/');

$ret      = [];

while (($entry = readdir($dir)) !== false) {
    $tmp = substr($entry, 0, strlen($username));

    # Does $entry start with $username?
    if ($tmp !== $username) continue;

    $ret[] = $entry;
}

print_r($ret);
```